# Hold OPAMP Integrator at zero voltage (Guarantee defined slew rate)

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, integrator

I have the following request:
I want to stop a common integrator (which should generate a defined slew rate for a square wave signal) exactly at zero (0 Volt) due to the return-to-zero coding of the interface.

[image]

In reality, the integrator will be supplied with a push-pull stage (+/- 5V), a third transistor would be switched against GND.

I have tried two comparators (LM393), whose output signal would be detected by a digital logic and the logic would then switch the push-pull stage to idle:
[image]

The problem: As you can already see in the simulation, there is a bigger phase offset (this is only the result of one comparator covering the positive threshold).

[image]

**Can anyone think of a simple and fast solution? Maybe just one transistor?**

Comment: "Exactly" means what? 0.1V? 1uV?

Comment: sorry: +/- 250 mV

Comment: You could use a single-supply rail-rail op-amp. That way it will naturally clamp at 0V.

Comment: Hmm, are you trying to make a three-level output? Or just two levels, 5V and 0V?

Comment: What do you mean with big phase offset? And can you clarify what you are trying to do with the comparators?

Comment: It is a three-level output +5V, -5V and 0V (Return-to-zero coding)

The comparators should work as zero crossing detectors (one comparator for positive thresold, one for negative)
"phase offset" -> Delay from comparators; of course I could change the threshold levels of the two comparators and check on which level the comparator output signal changes at about zero volt OPAMP-Integrator-output voltage, but this seems not robust enough to me.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the planned Zero-Crossing Detector with two comparators - It doesn't work in simulation somehow if I connect the two open-collector outputs of the LM393 (this should give an OR-circuit of the two comparators)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little crude, but I think it does what you are asking (sorry for the screen grab but links from the schematic editor are not working for me right now)

[image]

R2 and R3 bias Q1 so it turns on when the emitter is near 0V. They're not optimized and the turn-on will vary with temperature.

If you want something much more precise, consider a comparator driving an analog switch across C1.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will have a look at it.

"If you want something much more precise, consider a comparator driving an analog switch across C1. " - That would be almost like the above approach - except that I would use the comparator signal to idle the push-pull stage at the input and thus stop the current flow into the integrator.

Comment: The problem is the delay, slew rate is 5V/1.5us; between 0V and 250 mV, there are 75 ns to Stop integration; 
OR I set the threshold like in the above shown LM393 away from zero -> under consideration of the delay a stop in the range of zero could be guaranteed

Comment: There are much faster comparators than the antediluvian and glacially slow LM393, which is basically a truncated uncompensated LM358.

Comment: You are right- I have chosen the AD8561 now...